# Spring RestController ObjectMapper first request performance

Tags: spring, optimization, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I discovered that very first request to my restcontroller method take more time then others. I run JProfiler against my application and noticed that ObjectMapper is looking for deserializator in DeserializationContext class and when deserializator is not there new one is created. Is there a way to create object deserializator and put it to cache before first request?

Comment: Time difference between 0.001 sec to 0.003 sec?

Comment: No with JProfiler whole ObjectMapper takes near 500ms for the most compex object